# Привести multiclass classification в баланс в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классификация

День добрый.
У меня следующая проблема, есть задача классификации. На трэйне 50000 строк, на Y 60 лэйблов. Но данные несбалансированы (в одном классе, 35000 значений, в других 59 классах 15000 значений, из них в каких-то по 30 значений).
Если на примере, то есть X(column_1, column_2, column_3) и Y:

```
colum_1   colum_2   colum_2   Y
  0.5        1         2      1
  0.5        1.1       2      1
  0.55       0.95      3      1
  0.1        1         2      2
  2          0.9       3      3
```

А нужно добавить "зашумленные" данные, чтобы не было дисбаланса, условно, чтобы всех значений стало одинаково:

```
colum_1   colum_2   colum_2   Y
  0.5        1         2      1
  0.5        1.1       2      1
  0.55       0.95      3      1
  0.1        1         2      2
  0.15       0.99      2      2
  0.05       1.01      2      2 
  2          0.9       3      3
  1.95       0.95      3      3
  2.05       0.85      3      3
```

Только это игрушечный пример, а у меня много значений. Спасибо.

Comment: Какого рода у вас данные - картинки, оцифрованный/векторизированный текст, нечто другое? При помощи какого модуля / пакета делается классификация?

Comment: Пример данных такой же как я привел. В реальности просто больше колонок у X (порядка 400) и больше лэйблов у Y (60). В дальнейшем классификация делается в SVM.

Comment: Не понимая природы данных, трудно дать хороший совет. Например для картинок есть специальные функции, делающие `"data augmentation"`. По поводу "зашумления" данных - какие границы зашумления? почему `colum_2` не изменяется? `SVM` - это название алгоритма, а не модуля / библиотеки... Приведите соответствующую часть кода ([Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас действительно задача классификации, то зачем вам проводить балансирование объемов классов? Это такая задача сама по себе, или это надо потому, что у вас не сработали методы SVM?

С другой стороны, существуют методы (правда - "двухклассной", но тем не менее) классификации, способные проводить классификацию даже в случае, если у вас вовсе отсутствуют примеры второго класса. Гуглите по словосочетанию "One-class classification"

Наконец, если вы все-таки решитесь на балансрование (а это весьма рисковано, т.к. вы, именно в вашем случае,  по сути меняете закон распределения исходной выборки), смотрите в сторону методов ресэмплинга и бутсртапа.

Для затравки могу предложить:

1 В.К. Шитиков, Г.С. Розенберг. Рандомизация и бутстреп: статистический анализ в биологии и экологии с использованием R

2.С.Анатольев Основы бутстрапирования.

3.https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-bootstrap-method/